# should + gerund?

Tags: gerunds

What is the best to say

I sent a cd to a man and I emailed him three  days after sending the cd "You **should be getting** it soon" Is it correct or shall I say "you **should get** it soon". What is the difference

Comment: There is no gerund  after "should".

Answer (score 2):

Both

> You should be getting it soon.

and

> You should get it soon.

are grammatically correct.  They are essentially the same and both sound perfectly normal, at least to me (native AE speaker).  Any difference between them would be pedantic at most.

Comment: Perhaps the "should be getting" form conveys a bit more tentative connotation, vagueness about timeframe, etc., while "should get" seems a bit more direct and definite.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. Both mean the same thing in this context. 
In other contexts there might be a small difference in meaning.
Using BE + GERUND seems to be gaining in popularity. A McDonald's slogan is "I'm loving it" instead of "I love it".

Comment: An example where the meaning is a little different: *You should be traveling to Russia right now.* means "You're supposed to be on your way to Russia." whereas *You should travel to Russia right now.* means "You should leave for Russia immediately."